# Dynamic database record icons in the list module?

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3, is there is a way to render a thumbnail of an image 
contained inside an extension table as the icon for the record in the 
**list** module?The TCA documentation doesn't seem to say you can!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by using `typeicon_column` and `typeicons`. Example:

```
$TCA['tx_mytable'] = array (
    'ctrl' => array (
        'iconfile' => t3lib_extMgm::extPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Resources/Private/Icons/default.png',
        'typeicon_column' => 'mime_type',
        'typeicons' => array (
            'application/msword'                => 'gfx/fileicons/doc.gif',
            'application/msexcel'               => 'gfx/fileicons/xls.gif',
            'application/mspowerpoint'  => 'gfx/fileicons/ppt.gif',
            'application/pdf'                       => 'gfx/fileicons/pdf.gif',
            'application/zip'                       => 'gfx/fileicons/zip.gif',
            'image/bmp'                                 => 'gfx/fileicons/bmp.gif',
            'image/gif'                                 => 'gfx/fileicons/gif.gif',
            'image/jpeg'                                => 'gfx/fileicons/jpg.gif',
            'image/jpg'                                 => 'gfx/fileicons/jpg.gif',
        ),
    )
);
```

=> http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_api/4.2.0/view/4/2/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to import several different skins for the Typo3 backend, skins that changes the icons in used in the "List Module". For example t3skin and [t3skin_improved](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/t3skin_improved/current/).

I can't say what it would take to generate thumbnails and use them as icons, but there are several extensions that makes use of GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick to render thumbnails.

Comment: It is possible to change the icon in the list module. Place an icon file is your extension folder ext/your_extension and rename it to icon_tx_yourextension_tablename.gif.
and add make sure the below key-value is present in the $TCA['tx_yourextension_tablename']:
"'iconfile' => t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath($_EXTKEY).'icon_tx_yourextension_tablename.gif'" 

In my case, i want to change this icon dynamically for each row in the listing. ie. set the value of 'iconfile' based on some database value.Bt this doesnt seem to be possible unless i hack the getIcon function in class.t3lib_iconworks.php

Comment: Perhaps you'll get an answer emailing the team-members working with the list module. http://typo3.org/fileadmin/sponsored_projects/list_module_next_generation-v2.pdf